# Extract Expression Tree From Action

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm just starting out playing around with Linq Expressions and I've hit a wall.  I need to create an Expression Tree from an Action.  Unfortunetly I can't get the Action as an Expression, this is basically what I've got to work with:

```
public void Something(Action action){}
```

I need access to the body of the Action to extract variables and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Action` is not an `Expression`; it is simply a delegate (that might have been an expression at some point, might have been a lambda, and might not have been either).

To make this workable, you would need to refactor to:

```
public void Something(Expression<Action> action) {...}
```

Also, C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5 lambda expressions don't work very well for `Action`-type expressions. You are very limited in what you can express. `Func`-type expressions work better. In .NET 4.0 (CTP) there is [much more flexibility](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/future-expressions.html) here, although it still isn't clear what the language (C# 4.0) will offer by way of lambdas.

Basically, I'm not sure that you can (conveniently) do what you hope using `Expression`.

Comment: That's what I thought.  This is an Action coming from a Boo file, so luckly I can get access to the Boo expressions and get what I need :)